# Stepts for creating a Document object

Tags: java, dom, domdocument

I am learning about XML in Java and every time I want to use a Document object I have to write:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
```

I know how it works further, but what actually happens in those 3 lines? Why do I need a `DocumentBuilderFactory` and then a `DocumentBuilder` to build a `Document`?

Update: Could you give me an example where I shouldn't write the first 2 lines exactly the same? I don't see the point of instantiating 2 more objects for a new Document. What is their effective role?

Answer (score 1):

1) Factory (creates something) can create a DocumentBuilder

> Obtain a new instance of a DocumentBuilderFactory. This static method
>   creates a new factory instance.

2)

> Creates a new instance of a DocumentBuilder using the currently
>   configured parameters.

3)

> Parse the content of the given file as an XML document and return a
>   new DOM Document object. An IllegalArgumentException is thrown if the
>   File is null null.

[Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html#parse%28java.io.File%29)

This is how the library is build. Without the factory you will not be able to create a new DocumentBuilder object and thus will not be able to parse a file

Answer (score 1):

The approach you use for the XML parsing is known as the Document Object Model (DOM) approach (note: it is not the only one available) and a part of [Java API for XML Processing (JAXP)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/intro/index.html). Quoting:

> Designed to be flexible, JAXP allows you to use any XML-compliant
>   parser from within your application

To allow the programmer to use any XML parser, the system needs to avoid using a specific implementation. To be able to do that it decides the implementation during runtime using a design pattern known as the [Factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) which (quoting) *"...deals with the problem of creating objects (products) without specifying the exact class of object that will be created."*

So when you use `DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();` the returned instance is not actually a `DocumentBuilder` (it couldn't be - this is an `abstract` class) but an instance of another class that extends `DocumentBuilder`. You could print the actual class in runtime to verify that.

```
// returns com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl in my system
System.out.println( dbFactory.getClass().getName() );    

// returns com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl in my system
System.out.println( dBuilder.getClass().getName() );
```

Examples where you wouldn't need to use the first two lines, would be the cases where you would use a specific parsing implementation directly (and thus introducing a third party dependency in your project).

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Right from the javadocs:

**DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()**

> Obtain a new instance of a DocumentBuilderFactory. This static method
>   creates a new factory instance. This method uses the following ordered
>   lookup procedure to determine the DocumentBuilderFactory
>   implementation class to load:
>
> - Use the javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory system property.
> - Use the properties file "lib/jaxp.properties" in the JRE directory.    This configuration file is in standard java.util.Properties format
>     and contains the fully qualified name of the implementation class
>     with the key being the system property defined above. The
>     jaxp.properties file is read only once by the JAXP implementation and 
>     it's values are then cached for future use. If the file does not
>     exist when the first attempt is made to read from it, no further
>     attempts are made to check for its existence. It is not possible to
>     change the value of any property in jaxp.properties after it has been 
>     read for the first time.
> - Use the Services API (as detailed in the JAR specification), if    available, to determine the classname. The Services API will look for 
>     a classname in the file Platform default DocumentBuilderFactory
>     instance.
>     META-INF/services/javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory in jars
>     available to the runtime.
> - Platform default DocumentBuilderFactory instance.
>
> Once an application has obtained a reference to a
>   DocumentBuilderFactory it can use the factory to configure and obtain
>   parser instances.

**DocumentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder()**

> Creates a new instance of a DocumentBuilder using the currently
>   configured parameters.
>
> Returns: A new instance of a DocumentBuilder.
>
> Throws: ParserConfigurationException - if a DocumentBuilder cannot be
>   created which satisfies the configuration requested.

**DocumentBuilder.parse()**

> Parse the content of the given file as an XML document and return a
>   new DOM Document object. An IllegalArgumentException is thrown if the
>   File is null null.
>
> Parameters: f - The file containing the XML to parse.
>
> Returns: A new DOM Document object.
>
> Throws: IOException - If any IO errors occur. SAXException - If any
>   parse errors occur. IllegalArgumentException - When f is null